# Characteristic and minimal polynomial of Jordan Block

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I was wondering what the characteristic and minimal polynomial of a single Jordan Block are?
My guess was that they are always equal to each other and that it is just the polynomial that is (where n=number of rows/colums) $(x -\lambda)^n$, correct?

Comment: Yup. Correct. ${}$

Comment: That's right...but why "guess"? If you know how a  matrix in Jordan block looks then this should be obvious: an upper (or lower, depending) triangular matrix with lots of zeros...